# One button with two functions (Button add to favorites)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("HeartSpanImage")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
            this.classList.remove("active");
        } else this.classList.add("active");
        })
```

```css
    body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .cardOfFavorite{
        position: relative;
    }

    .HeartSpanImage{
        margin-right: 5px;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: grey;
    }

    .HeartSpanImage:active{
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }
    .HeartSpanImage.active{
        color: red;
    }

    .HeartSpanImage:focus> .imageHide{
        display: block;
    }

    .HeartSpanImage:hover, .HeartSpanImage:focus{
        color: red;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
```

```html
<head>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="containerOfFavorite">
    <div class="cardOfFavorite" style="border: 5px solid red; width:250px; display:flex;
               flex-direction:column; justify-content:center; align-items: center;
               padding: 7px; position: relative; cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="material-icons HeartSpanImage active delete-itemFavorite" id="HeartSpanImage" data-name="name" data-price="1.50"> favorite </span>       
        <img class="amico" src="https://www.corsair.com/de/de/medias/sys_master/images/images/h1d/he3/9950073159710/CS-9020031-PE/Gallery/CORSAIR_ONE_i300_2022_01/-CS-9020031-PE-Gallery-CORSAIR-ONE-i300-2022-01.png_515Wx515H" alt="" width="150px">
        <img src="" class="imageHide" id="imageHide"></img>
        <h3 style="color: red;">Title</h3>
        <label style="color:grey;" for="">$1.50</label>
    </div>
      
</body>
```

I have a question about the add to favorites button, did any one of you, before, designed the javascript codes for this button?
I wanted to design the button so that 1- When you click the button, the product is added to the favorites list
2- When you click the button again, the item is deleted from the favorites list
How can the two functions work with one button?

Comment: So how do you add it to favorites? Start with that. Show your code. In the end it is not two functions. It is just one function call. You check the state of the favorite and you handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You already got your if statement checking/storing the state of the favorite (heart). Use that.

From what I can tell, you got data-* attributes on your favorite icon. I would also add an unique `data-id`, specific for that product, because using `name` will sometimes create certain problems.

You can get data-* attributes through a `dataset` property, as shown in the example below.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("HeartSpanImage")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  let name =  this.dataset.name;
  let price = this.dataset.price;

  if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
    this.classList.remove("active");
    addToFavorites(name, price);
  } else {
    this.classList.add("active");
    removeFromFavorites(name, price);
  }
})
```

What `addToFavorites()` and `removeFromFavorites()` is up to you. You haven't written any information of how you should store this, let it sending it to a server och saving it on the user's disk via `localStorage`.

Comment: First of all, thank you, but it did not work to remove the item from the favourites by removingFromFavorites(name, price); I will write you the function that I designed, and you can help me how to delete the elements by
document.getElementsByClassName("HeartSpanImage")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
   let name = this.dataset.name;
   let price = this.dataset.price;

   if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
     this.classList.remove("active");
     addToFavorites(name, price);
   } else {
     this.classList.add("active");
     removeFromFavorites(name, price);
   }})

Comment: const FavoriteList = (function() {

// =============================
// Private methods and propeties
// =============================
let cart = [];
// Constructor
class Item {
  constructor(name, price, count, image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.count = count;
    this.image = image;
  }
}
// Save cart
function saveCart() {
  localStorage.setItem('FavoriteList', JSON.stringify(cart));
}

Comment: // Load cart
function loadCart() {
  cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavoriteList'));
}
if (localStorage.getItem("FavoriteList") != null) {
  loadCart();
}
const obj = {};

// Add to cart
obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count, image) {
  for (let item in cart) {
    if (cart[item].name === name) {
      cart[item].count += count ||  1
      saveCart();
      return;
    }
  }
  let item = new Item(name, price, count, image);
  cart.push(item);
  saveCart();
}

Comment: // Clear cart
obj.clearCart = function() {
  cart = [];
  saveCart();
}
// Remove item from cart
obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
  for (let item in cart) {
    if (cart[item].name === name) {
      cart[item].count--;
      if (cart[item].count === 0) {
        cart.splice(item, 1);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  saveCart();
}

Comment: // Add item
$('.HeartSpanImage').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
let name =  $(this).data('name');
let price = Number($(this).data('price'));
let image = $(this).parents("div.containerOfProducts").find(".ImageOfProduct1").attr('src');
let count = parseInt($(this).parents("div.card").find(".item-count").val());
FavoriteList.addItemToCart(name, price, count, image);
displayCart();
});

Comment: // Clear items
$('.clear-cart-items').click(function() {
 FavoriteList.clearItem();
displayCart();
});

Comment: function displayCart() {
let cartArray = FavoriteList.listCart();
let output = "";
for (let i in cartArray) {
  output += "<tr class='cartFavorite'>" +
    "<td><img src='" + cartArray[i].image + "' style='width:120px;'></td>" +
    "<td class='FavoriteTitle'>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + cartArray[i].price +'€' + "</td>" +
    "<td><button class='delete-itemFavorite btn btn-danger' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'>X</button></td>" +
    " = " +
    "</tr>"
    + "<tr>";

}
$('.modalOfFavorite').html(output);
}

Comment: // Delete item button

$('.modalOfFavorite').on("click", ".delete-itemFavorite", function(event) {
let name = $(this).data('name')
FavoriteList.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
displayCart();
})


displayCart();